# RTOS on ARM microcontroller: why do we save the state of registers R4-R11 upon context switching

Tags: arm, cpu-registers, rtos, context-switch

I am wondering why every course and resource on RTOS for ARM microcontrollers tells to save the state of registers R4 to R11 upon context switching.

For interrupts that are not related to context switching, we don't care of saving the state of these registers. So when one of these interrupts occurs in the middle of the execution of a thread, it will use and "corrupt" these registers.

Then, why do we want to save the state of these registers after that ?

Comment: is your handler purely hand written assembly language?

Comment: @old_timer only the one that is responsible for the context switching (SysTick Handler in my case).

Comment: the others are in a compiled language?

Comment: I guess you are referring to a Cortex-M.  It is important to specify which type of ARM CPU you mean when talking about ISR and exception models.  Sorry if I somehow missed this key point in your question.  You might make it more obvious if you think it is there.  For instance, by tagging with 'cortex-m' and stating it explicitly.  Perhaps you don't know the difference and rely on Cortex-A and traditional ARM exception models, as a source of information and then see other documents that refer to the Cortex-M model?

Comment: Context switches do not only occur in SysTick Handler, the scheduler runs whenever a scheduling function is called from a thread or on exit from the interrupt context if a scheduling function was called from the interrupt context.  In fact in most true real time systems, context switching is in response to asynchronous events, not time triggered.

Answer (score 0):

> For interrupts that are not related to context switching, [...]

In a real-time operating system, context switches can occur as a result of any interrupt handler that invokes a scheduling function such as a sem- give or queue-send (non- blocking).  It is a mistake to think the scheduler runs only as a result of systick.  That is the case for delay expiry and timer events only. The scheduler also runs when scheduling functions are called from the thread context

> [...] we don't care of saving the state of these registers.

You do care, but on ARM Cortex-M at least, the registers are saved and restored automatically by the hardware.

> So when one of these interrupts occurs in the middle of the execution of a thread, it will use and "corrupt" these registers.

Not the case. On Cortex-M, on entry to an ISR, the registers are automatically preserved.  When a scheduling function is called from the interrupt, the stored context is preserved, not the interrupt context.  The stored return address is modified to cause the scheduler to run on exit from the interrupt context, the registers are restored by hardware, and the scheduler runs, switching or restoring context as necessary.

The precise details may vary between implementations, but that is in outline how it works.  The important point is that thread context is automatically preserved on entry to the interrupt context.  And also again on entry to a nested interrupt from some lower priority interrupt.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100166/0001/Programmers-Model/Exceptions/Exception-handling-and-prioritization?lang=en